# Is this code blocking bots from crawling my page?

Tags: html, asp.net, .htaccess, web

My website used to have a really high index on google, yahoo and bing. But suddenly it totally disappeared from all.

I've resubmitted to google, created a sitemap etc to try and re-index my website with no success. So I read about checking my .htaccess file to see if I have been hacked.

I have come accross the following in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(bot|urp|msn).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) 501.html [NS,NC,L]
```

Is someone able to tell me if this is blocking bots from crawling my page or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I imagine that would have an effect like what you've described. Why on earth would you want to have code doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this rule blocks their access to your web site. Remove those three line to give them proper access. If you want to prevent them from accessing special part of your web-site, use **robots.txt** instead.